# How to change the color of a placeholder in a GWT element

Tags: java, gwt

I have the following code that changes placeholder of a text box in GWT:

```
A.getElement().setAttribute("placeholder", "please enter name:");

//getElement returns an instance of "com.google.gwt.user.client.Element"
```

**Question:** How to change the color of this element placeholder to something else (like red) and then change it back to its default?

Comment: Three words [Cascading Style Sheets](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/style-placeholder-text/).

Comment: @BoristheSpider That is true; how you add it to GWT. Can you please put it as an answer. Not sure how this works with GWT.

Comment: You're sure how to use CSS with GWT? I think that's far too broad a topic for this Q&A. Suffice it to say that you should probably learn. How do you style _anything_ if you don't know how to use CSS with GWT?

Answer (score 0):

Add a new style in your stylesheet.css and add it to your input element.
Heres an easy example:

```
A.getElement().setAttribute("placeholder", "please enter name:");
// add the style for a red text
A.addStyleName("redPlaceHolder");
// remove it when youre done and it will change back to default
// A.removeStyleName("redPlaceHolder");
```

css:

```
.redPlaceHolder::-webkit-input-placeholder {
   color: red;
}

.redPlaceHolder:-moz-placeholder {
   color: red;  
}

.redPlaceHolder::-moz-placeholder {  
   color: red;  
}

.redPlaceHolder:-ms-input-placeholder {  
   color: red;  
}
```

JSFiddle example
https://jsfiddle.net/4zydnufe/1/